# In a python for loop, is there a reason overwriting the value of dictionary2 where previously stated 'dictionary1 = dictionary2' also updates dict1?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm self-taught (without the taught part for now), so I apologize if the question is dumb or self-explanatory. I can't seem to phrase the issue in a way to find existing queries on the same topic, so here goes anyway.

in the following (out of context) code snippets, I can't find the reason the outputs should be different:

```
set1 = {}
    
for i in s1:
for j in range(1,len(i)):
        set1[i[j][0]] = i[j][1]
    set2[i[0]] = set1
```

...and...

```
for i in s1:
set1 = {}
for j in range(1,len(i)):
        set1[i[j][0]] = i[j][1]
    set2[i[0]] = set1
```

... where s1 is a list of lists structured as `[name, [value, pair] [value, pair]]` and the desired output is `{name: {value: pair, value:pair}, name2: ...}`

I understand the second approach is necessary anyway if it isn't guaranteed that each list in s1 has all the same values represented. I dont understand why the first approach returns a dictionary where all values for each name (key) are the same, when `set2[i[0]] = set1` is executed for different values of set1

I understand the reason has something to do with Python passing a reference instead of a copy of the data... I don't understand why the same doesn't seem true when doing similar operations like:

```
dictionary1 = {}
dictionary2 = {1:'a', 2:'b'}

dictionary1 = dictionary2

dictionary2 = {1:'f', 2:'g'}
```

...where dictionary1 is fed a copy of dictionary2 and is independent of it down the line

Any help is appreciated. Again, sorry if duplicate or otherwise dumb

Comment: You'll want to fix the indentation of the code examples - like this they're the same in that neither will work. It would also be helpful if you provide some sample data or at least a basic description of the content of `s1`. It's also unclear what results you're getting, how they're different and what result you wanted/expected. The example you give with `dict` at the end has its own (unrelated) issues, so I don't think it helps to clarify your question, it just distracts from what you're asking.

Comment: Related: [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](/q/2612802/4518341)

Comment: Beside the point, but you don't even need the inner loop. You can use `set2[i[0]] = dict(i[1:])`

Comment: Your first code snippet has exactly two dictionary objects.  One is bound to `set1`, and one is bound to `set2`.  All the values of `set2` are the same dict -- the one also called `set1`.  Your inner loop CHANGES that dictionary, but it's always the same object.  Your second one contains many different dictionaries -- each outer loop creates a new object, so each element of `set2` contains a different object.

Comment: In Python, an assignment statement like `dictionary1 = dictionary2` just gives another name (the one on the left) to an object (the one with the name on the right). Now that one object has two names, and you can modify that one object using either name.

Comment: Read this: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 0):

In general, python dictionaries work by reference or pointer. But it also depends on what kind of operation you apply on the object that we point to.
Example:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {'hello': l}
print(d) # Out: {'hello': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
l[3] = -1
print(d) # Out: {'hello': [1, 2, 3, -1]}
```

This is because the `l[3] = -1` operation maintains the pointers. However:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {'hello': l}
print(d) # Out: {'hello': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
l = 24
print(d) # Out: {'hello': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

In this second example the operation `l=24` does not work with pointers, but "detaches the pointers of `l`" and creates a new object `l` that is now a integer in this case.

In your example, something similar happens, where `set = {}` kind of "detaches" the references of the previous `set1` that is now in `set2` from the object `set1` that you have in this loop iteration. However, only doing `set1[i[j][0]] = i[j][1]` would not produce such detachment and you would be accessing the object that is in `set2`.